# Android Wear smartwatch Samsung Gear Live won't turn on, while charging

Tags: samsung, shutdown, android-wear

I have the Android Wear smartwatch [**Samsung Gear Live**](http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/gear/gearlive_design.html) and it wont turn on. When I'm trying to turn it on while charging (and it was charging for at least 3 hours) it will show the initial logo, then the booting animations and at one point before completing the screen will turn black. When pressing the button to turn on again it shows the charging battery animation.

Is there anything I can do to hard reset maybe?!

I tried to hold the button for long time or unplugging it from the power supply, but it keeps trying to boot and stops without success.

Comment: Someone with 300+ maybe could create the `samsung-gear-live` tag :)

Comment: What happens when you plug in to charge?  Does the display show the large battery that fills up?  I'm wondering if it's not charging properly, because what you describe sounds a lot like what would happen if you tried to turn it on with minimal battery.  I've heard reports of the watch being unable to properly charge from an outlet after long periods of inactivity, where the (inexplicable) fix is to let the first ~5% charge while connected to a laptop, then plug into the wall, did you go a week+ with it powered down and out of battery?

Comment: @MattDavis actually it was a battery issue after all.. so my charger is not working.. I tried with another one and it work.. which brings us to another problem obviously, but it's unrelated with the watch! So I might delete that question completely..

Answer (score -1):

most of the time they will charge from a laptop usb and not an outlet.Also if you take it apart and disconnect the battery it will fire up 90 percent of the time.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, laptop ports are frequently underpowered compared to wall chargers and not the other way around.